# Rust: How to perform arithmetic on a Vec of items

Tags: rust

I've got code to write where there is a common idiom where I have a `Vec<f64>` and I have to perform some arithmetic on it.

Sometimes I want to modify the Vec in place, and other times I want to create  new Vec with the results of the operation.

What is the idiomatic way to do each of these in Rust?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modify in place:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut data: Vec<f64> = vec![1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0];

    for el in &mut data {
        *el *= 2.0;
    }

    println!("{:?}", data);
}
```

```
[2.0, 4.0, 6.0, 8.0]
```

Create a new `Vec` with the results:

```rust
fn main() {
    let data: Vec<f64> = vec![1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0];

    let results: Vec<f64> = data.iter().map(|el| el * 2.0).collect();

    println!("Original: {:?}", data);
    println!("Results: {:?}", results);
}
```

```
Original: [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
Results: [2.0, 4.0, 6.0, 8.0]
```

### Background

`for el in &mut data` iterates over `data` mutably without consuming it. `el` is a `&mut f64` that directly references the item in the vector; modifying it directly modifies the vector content.

`data.iter()` creates an iterator over the elements of `data` without consuming `data`. `.map()` then applies an operation to each element and returns a new iterator over the results. `.collect()` then consumes all elements of the iterator and collects it into whatever it's supposed to create; in this case a `Vec<f64>` due to the type annotation after `results`. The pattern `.iter().map().collect()` is fairly common in Rust and is worth being remembered.

Comment: Very succinct. Thanks!